# TerminateProcess() doesn't close the application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, terminate, shellexecute

I am trying to use the TerminateProcess to terminate an app launched by ShellExecuteEX like this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ExecuteInfo;
ExecuteInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI; /* Odd but true */
ExecuteInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ExecuteInfo.cbSize = sizeof(ExecuteInfo);
ExecuteInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ExecuteInfo.lpFile = "http://www.microsoft.com";
ExecuteInfo.lpParameters = "";
ExecuteInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ExecuteInfo.nShow =  SW_SHOW;;
ShellExecuteEx(&ExecuteInfo);
//WaitForSingleObject(ExecuteInfo.hProcess, 0);
Sleep(4000);
TerminateProcess(ExecuteInfo.hProcess, 0);
```

IE gets opened but it never closes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not verifying that `ShellExecuteEx` returned `TRUE` is wrong. ;-]

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx), it doesn't exit until all pending I/O completes or cancels.  Being a browser, there's probably plenty of I/O happening.  I have understood that you should never try to kill a process, particularly in this way.  Perhaps you should do the same and instead request the process to exit (in whatever way that is done)?

Comment: @JeffMercado : Typically one would send the main thread the `WM_CLOSE` message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `fMask` must be set to `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` for `.hProcess` to get set. I would add a test to see if it is NULL. As a side note I've always had better luck using [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:**

This is how you do it using CreateProcess:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;


CreateProcess(  NULL,
                "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe http://www.google.com/",
                NULL,
                NULL,
                FALSE,
                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &si,
                &pi );


Sleep(4000);
TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
```

You should add error-checking and could query the path of the default browser using: [`AssocQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:
`AssocQueryString(0,ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,"http","open", szExe, &cchExe);`

Comment: Agreed, consider CreateProcess.

Comment: @Robb : I changed fMask to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS and hProcess is still NULL, also tried CreateProcess, and hProcess is still null :S

Comment: @riviraz - I updated to show how to do it using `CreateProcess` it will work unless there is an existing window already open, then it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information by checking the returned hProcess (e.g., in a debugger).  Also make sure you have the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag set.

But my psychic powers say:  Opening an IE document doesn't necessarily create a new process.  And, if it does, it may not be the one you think it is:  The process you may have created may have spawned yet another process to actually host the document.  Raymond Chen mentions that about halfway down [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/05/590749.aspx).

Comment: I tried debugging and hProcess is always null either in shellexecuteex and createprocess.

Comment: Which is consistent with my theory that IE isn't creating a new process to open the document.  (Or that the process it launched caused another process to host the document, and the original process exits.)  In other words, you can't do what you're trying to do.